# How can I write query in mulipage

Tags: php

I write code php to check ID and Password

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> p1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="p2.php" method="get">
    ID:<input type="text" name="id" />
    Password:<input  type="password" name="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

then in p2 this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> page 1</title>
<body>
<?php
$get_id= $_GET['id'];
$get_pass = $_GET['pass'];
$name = "";

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
{
    die("not ok");
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  

$q = " SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = " . $get_id ." and password = " . $get_pass;
$result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row["name"];
   echo $row["id"];
}
?>
<p> academic transcript  <a href="tran.php">here</a></p>
<p> academic transcript  <a href="courses.php">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

the question 
how I can write select statement in tran.php or courses.php pages to get the information form database by click on this link here

without enter the ID again.

I mean click on this link here

then direct will execute the query (select statement) without enter the ID again

Comment: sidenote: sending sensitive information via GET, is a bad idea. Especially passwords and using plain text on top of that.

Comment: you also have a syntax error but I guess that's not what the question's about then.

Comment: Can't you just store the logged-in user info in session state?  Also note that your code is *wide open* to SQL injection.  You're basically executing any code that your users feel like sending you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sessions.

put:

```
session_start();
```

at the top of the php file.

Then to save data to the session, you put

```
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
```

(honestly this is a bad way of doing it ) - you should be using a php framework like Laravel or Symfony,CakePHP, CodeIgnitor, etc etc

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php